# prepared statement bind variable doesnt return 0 when it should

Tags: php, prepared-statement

In the following code, if **$get_artist** is a primary key that doesn't exist in the database, then the bind variable **$artistid** should always return 0, right? But it doesn't and it always returns nothing, not 0, nothing!
Why?

```
if (isset($_GET['artist']) && is_numeric($_GET['artist'])) {
   $get_artist = (int)$_GET['artist'];
}

$sql = 'SELECT artist_id, name, legal_name, photo_basename
        FROM artist
        WHERE artist_id = ?';
$conn = connect('read');
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $get_artist);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
$stmt->bind_result($artistid, $name, $legalname, $photo);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();


// if $get_artist is an invalid primary key, it should echo 0, right?
echo $artistid;
```

Comment: Why should it result in zero, if the query does not return that value? No, it ought to be NULL for absent entries.

Comment: i was under the impression that when given a invalid number, $artistid always returns 0. I even read it in the book 'PHP solutions Dynamic Web design Made easy' page 356

Comment: just went live with my site and it turns out that it does return 0 when id is invalid... go figure... probably something to do a config or else, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the query doesn't return any rows, the variables (including `$artistid`) are never filled in.

You can check the [return value of `$stmt->fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php). If it is `null`, there were no (more) rows. If it returns `null` the very first time you call it, that means there were no result rows at all and your variables will not be set to anything (so the PHP default of `null` will probably apply).

Comment: ok, so my impression that it returns 0 is totally wrong. Also, instead of checking the return value of fetch, i could use $num_rows since it returns the number of rows in result set